# AngularJS Laravel 5 JWT tokens Satellizer

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

I have a Laravel back-end API that is connected to an AngularJS app, where the authentication is with JWT tokens using the Satellizer package. Until now I only had one type of user, but I want to introduce admins, so I added a `role` column to the User table. When the user logs in, and if he's an admin, it would redirect to a view on the Laravel side. If it's a normal user, it will return a token which then redirects to the normal website on the AngularJS side.

However I'm having some trouble accomplishing this. This is the login method:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $email = $request->input('email');
    $password = $request->input('password');
    $user = User::where('email', '=', $email)->first();
    if (!$user)
    {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Wrong email and/or password'], 401);
    }
    if (Hash::check($password, $user->password))
    {
        unset($user->password);
        return response()->json(['token' => $this->createToken($user)]);
    }
    else
    {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Wrong email and/or password'], 401);
    }
}
```

And I thought it would be as simple as adding this:

```
if($user->role == "admin"){
        return view('index');
    }
```

Anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you putting that "$user->role ==" code?  The login function has to return the token back to the angular app so it knows how to authenticate with the rest of the application.  If you just inject your code there, it's going to not send back the token, and he'll never be authenticated ...

Comment: I'm putting it after the `if (!$user)` flow. Since the view is in laravel and the whole back-office for the admin is going to be in Laravel, do I still need to return a token to the angular app?

Comment: I'm not familiar with laravel, so I can't answer that directly, but typically the server has to give the client a credential.  Even if it's not angular, you'd have to set a cookie, for instance, so the server can validate the session for the client.